# Can't push to remote

Tags: git

I am pushing my changes to git but I have this problem:

```
C:\Work\eclipse-ws\teatre_de_guerrilla>git push
Counting objects: 27, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Writing objects: 100% (27/27), 2.02 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 27 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Hook com.isroot.stash.plugin.YaccHook failed. Error:
remote: An error occurred while executing an external process: 2
```

Comment: Check with your git host admin. The stash hook "YaccHook" failed.